# How to append .php using the htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

Currently on my site I'm using statements like:

```
include 'head.php'; 
include 'footer.php';
```

i wanted to add the .php dynamically using the .htaccess, is that possible to do. SO that there is no need for me to add .php in code every time when where i add the php page using the include or require method

Expected output is

```
include 'head'; 
include 'footer';
```

Comment: I think this is not a big overhead, don't do something that not useful for code usability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.htaccess files can be used to modify the behaviour of the *web server* which is hosting your PHP app. When an HTTP request comes in without the trailing .php, you can use htaccess to make the web server invoke the file *with* .php nonetheless. That's a feature supported by the *web server*. All this is irrelevant once PHP is invoked. `include` is a PHP statement which is evaluated by PHP according to PHP's rules. PHP doesn't know or care about .htaccess files. PHP requires you to provide the complete path to a file you want to include. What you want is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible man! If the goal is to avoid repeating `.php` every time, Consider creating a php function, such as `my_include`

```
   function my_include(filename){
        include filename.'.php';
   }
```

Then calls are

```
my_include('head');
my_include('foo');
my_include('bar');
my_include('footer');
```

**EDITS:**  This function is useful, you can check whether if the file exists or not. This in order to avoid exception

```
   function my_include(filename){            
        include file_exists(filename.'.php')?filename.'.php':'404.php';
   }
```

And the `404.php` may look like

```
  <?php
   echo 'some content were not found';
  ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

#### That is not possible with `.htaccess`.

You can rename them using your favorite IDE as this is not the job of `.htaccess` and it cannot read the *inner* logic of your PHP code.

Solution is replacing them using your PHP IDE , even a Notepad can help.

Comment: your are also correct i accepted the other answer because of his detailed explanation. Thanks for  your answer